# Setup user role read/edit project by project, Django ORM

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to implement a relationship between three tables; `User` `Project` and `Permissions`

I already have a `ManyToMany` relationship between `User` and `Project`

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
  username = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=20, null=False, blank=False)
  // etc...

class Project(models.Model):
  user = models.ManyToManyField(CustomUser, related_name="projects")
```

Now I am trying to add the Permission Table. So that `User` can take different roles on different project.

```
class Permissions(models.Model):
  can_read = models.BooleanField(default=True)
  can_read_and_edit = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  // etc...
```

What is the best approach on this situation. Should I Add `Permission` table into **manytomany** relation as a third table? Or is there a better way to achieve this

Comment: I think a better way is to define a through table that holds the project, user and permission id

Comment: could you make an example for that relationship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom `through` model to add details to the Many-to-many relation like this:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    pass


class Project(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField(CustomUser, through='ProjectDetails')


class Permission(models.Model):
    pass


class ProjectDetails(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    permission = models.ForeignKey(Permission, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

This way, each user for a project can be assigned a certain permission (per project). You can also add more details about a certain user's involvement in a project. For example, when they started in a project.

If you want to learn more, you can have a read [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships).